# Convergence/divergence of a sequence (including sine function)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to figure out if the following sequences are convergent or divergent.

$$a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n) \cdot n^{-1/2}$$

$$b=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{n\cdot π}{2}+\frac{π}{3}\right)n^{1/2}$$

As I understand it I need to find the limits of the above. But I am uncertain how to go about it.

Comment: For (a), [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).  For (b), do the terms go to $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the well known fact that $\sum_{n=1}^N\sin(n)$ is bounded for all $N$ and that $1/\sqrt n$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$ to show by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) that the first sum converges.

Then use the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) to show that the second sum diverges since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}2+\frac\pi3\right)n^{1/2}\ne0$$

Comment: You might consider saying what $M$ is.

Comment: @Dr.MV It is at most $3$ or so and can easily be derived via the geometric series and complex definition of sine.

Comment: I know that.  That's not what I meant.  You ought to write that there is a constant $M$ that works for all $N$.  Or just say that the sum is bounded by a number independent of $N$..

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the clarification of the wordings.  @Dr.MV

Comment: Sure.  But not simply bounded.  There is a single number that works for all $N$.

Comment: A sum is a number, so it doesn't make sense calling it bounded. The point (or better wording) is that that sum is bounded as a function of $N$

Comment: @Emilio but for what $N$?  I think it is better worded as bounded for all $N$.

Comment: When you bound a function, then by definition all images are bounded by the same number, without need of specifying an $N$ or saying "for all $N$". I  prefer bounding one function than bounding a number with a quantifier ($\forall$), but I admit that it's a matter of preference

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the sandwich/sqeeze theorom, as it was something I've gone over before (which Albits is not). But I am uncertain how I can find the limit of the expression. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: It is the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) @Sirmimer

Comment: Sorry simple art, i forgot to "check answered". I keep hitting "upvote" instead of it. Still learning how stackexchange works. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Sirmimer no problem, it all takes time

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (Dirichlet's test)

If

- $(u_n)$ is decreasing
- $\lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n=0$
- $\exists M>0 \;: \forall n\geq 0 $

$$|v_0+v_1+...+v_n|\leq M$$

then $\sum u_n.v_n$ converges.

take $u_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $v_n=\sin(n).$

> for the second

$u_n=\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{3})n^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}u_{4n}=$

$=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt{3n}=+\infty$

$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n\neq 0$

$\implies \sum u_n$ diverges.

Comment: When i look up Abel's test, it says that it is a test for series. Does it work for sequences as well?

Comment: When I look up Abel's test, I definitely do not get what is here.

Comment: :D No worries!  It just seemed... wrong, as it was.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  (+1)

Comment: Hm, but it doesn't answer the second series.